# Error en variable no definida en Python

Tags: python, mysql

Tengo una aplicación de un login donde al momento de loguearme él me trae unos datos de la base de datos ya que tengo relacionadas unas tablas, entonces el proceso es el siguiente: el usuario se loguea y si sus credenciales son correctas toma unos datos de la base de datos y los almacena en unas variables.
Tengo dos procedimientos iguales pero resulta que uno de ellos no me funciona: me dice que la variable que intento usar en la siguiente consulta no está definida y las consultas ya las probé en la base de datos y me funciona porque me trae los datos que necesito. Ya intenté muchas cosas y ninguna me funciona.

A continuación les enseño el código:

```
def validacion_datos():
    global usuario
    global constrasena
    global idUsuario
    
    # global capturaDato

    db = pymysql.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        password="1234",
        database="db123"
    )

    lcursor = db.cursor()
    pcursor = db.cursor()

    lcursor.execute("SELECT id FROM login WHERE usuario='"+nombreusuario_verify.get()+"' AND contrasena='"+contrasenausuario_verify.get()+"' AND id")
    capturaID = lcursor.fetchall()
    for row in capturaID:
        idUsuario = row[0]
    print(idUsuario)


    pcursor.execute("SELECT ventas.usuario, ventas.contrasena FROM login INNER JOIN ventas ON login.id=ventas.id_usuario WHERE login.id={}".format(idUsuario))
    capturaDato = pcursor.fetchall()
    for row in capturaDato:
        usuario = row[0]
        constrasena = row[1]
    print(usuario)
    print(constrasena)

    if lcursor:
        messagebox.showinfo(title="Inicio de Sesión Correcto", message="Usuario y Contraseña Correcta")
        if pcursor:
            messagebox.showinfo(title="Validación Correcta", message="Validación Correcta")
            login()
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo(title="Validación Incorrecta", message="Validación Incorrecta")      
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo(title="Inicio de Sesión Incorrecto", message="Usuario y Contraseña Incorrecta")

    db.close()
```

Aquí está el error que me arroja la terminal:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\\OneDrive\Escritorio\Desarrollo\interfaz.pyw", line 177, in validacion_datos
    print(idUsuario)
NameError: name 'idUsuario' is not defined
```

Comment: Me parece ya haber visto esta pregunta. En varias preguntas tenés títulos ambiguos: para hacer a la pregunta más atractiva, escribe en el título el problema _específico_ que estás teniendo. Lee [ask].

Comment: `idUsuario` está definida fuera de la función?

Comment: No solo la tengo en esa función y ya @CésarGonzález

Comment: @JuanSebastianAriasRobayo entonces tiene sentido lo que te está ocurriendo. Estás utilizando `global` con una variable de la función que no está al nivel del módulo, por lo que puede darse el caso de que no esté definida al hacer `print(idUsuario)` si tu query no te devuelve resultados.

Comment: y que debo hacer solo quitar la palabra reservada `global` ?

Comment: Depende de lo que quieras hacer. Si tu idea es modificar el valor de esa variable desde la función que has hecho y tenerla disponible para otras funciones deberías declararla fuera y mantener el global. Si lo que quieres es utilizarla unicamente dentro de la función el global no te hace falta, pero tendrías que declararla dentro de la función para que no lance una excepción al intentar acceder a ella cuando aún no existe.

Comment: No solo la necesito en esa función en especifico ya la deje `None` y voy ha proceder a probarla a ver si funciona